# How to map binary data in a SpringData MongoDb Java bean?

Tags: java, spring, mongodb

I have a bean that includes a Java object that is stored as binary data in Mongo DB.
Introducing SpringData  for mapping gave me the problem.
So, the Bean code is:

```
@Document(collection = “cache”)
public class CacheBean {
    ... 
    private Object objectData;
    ...
}
```

The insertion code to Mongo Db is:

```
protected void setToMongo(String key, Object value){
    ByteArrayOutputStream b = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ObjectOutputStream o = new ObjectOutputStream(b);
    o.writeObject(value);
    CacheBean cacheBean = new CacheBean();
    cacheBean.setObjectData(getBytesForObject(o));
    mongoTemplate.save(cacheBean);
}
private byte[] getBytesForObject(Object o) throws IOException{
    ByteArrayOutputStream b = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ObjectOutputStream os = new ObjectOutputStream(b);
    os.writeObject(o);
    return b.toByteArray();
}
```

The extraction code is as follows:

```
Object resultObject = cacheBean.getObjectData();
org.bson.types.Binary result = (Binary) resultObject;
ByteArrayInputStream b = new ByteArrayInputStream(result.getData());
ObjectInputStream o = new ObjectInputStream(b);
return o.readObject();
```

I am getting the exception on the line

```
org.bson.types.Binary result = (Binary) resultObject:
```

java.lang.ClassCastException: [B cannot be cast to org.bson.types.Binary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MongoDB implicitly store (I think) byte array as Bson BinData.

Note that you yourself set the objectData to a byte array:

```
cacheBean.setObjectData(getBytesForObject(o));
```

At that point `private Object objectData;` is of type `byte[]`

So there is nothing preventing you from declaring this in `CacheBean`:

```
private byte[] objectData;
```

And therefore...

```
ByteArrayInputStream b = new ByteArrayInputStream(cacheBean.getObjectData());
ObjectInputStream o = new ObjectInputStream(b);
return o.readObject();
```

For convenience, you may also want to store the object class as a field.

Comment: I actually used the same idea but I stored objectData as org.bson.types.Binary instead of byte[]